# If a matrix $A^2$ is invertible, is $A^3$ invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse

I know how to find out if a matrix  $A^2$ is invertible if $A^3$ is invertible, but how can you find out invertibility if it's the the other way around?

Comment: Determinants make it easy.

Answer (score 8):

A matrix is invertible if and only if it has a nonzero determinant.  Since $\det(A^2) = \det(A)\det(A)$, if $\det(A^2) \neq 0$, then $\det(A) \neq 0$.

Answer (score 4):

We only need the definition and associativity.

By definition since $A^2$ is invertible, there exists a matrix $M$ such that $A^2M=I$, where I is the identity matrix. Now, consider the matrix $AM^2$. Then, by associativity, we have the following.
$$A^3(AM^2) = A^2(A^2M)M=A^2M=I$$
Therefore, we know that the $A^3$ is invertible and its inverse is $AM^2$.